# Gradle: No such property for class?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am trying to compile an existing codebase using the newest version of `gradle`. The build fails due to the following line in the modules `build.gradle` file:

```
project.setProperty("doNow", true)
```

with this error:

```
 No such property: doNow for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
```

Do I need to declare this property within build.gradle before the line causing an error?

From gradle docs for `setProperty`:

> Sets a property of this project. This method searches for a property
>   with the given name in the following locations, and sets the property
>   on the first location where it finds the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `project.ext.doNow = 'lol'`

Comment: It creates the property which can be set later on.

Comment: Gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html